# How to modify object in for loop? React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new in react native , I want to insert new value into every object of array.

I have successfully implemented the logic according to object value. Condition is working right, I have checked by console.log() the statement working right but when I print the my final output array the new value of every object is same, value not assign different in object according to condition.

Here is the code which I am using:-

```
var newOffers = [];
response.data.forEach((element) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < element.frequency; i++) {
    var offer = element;
    if (offer.used == 0) {
      offer.isAvailable = "true";
      newOffers.push(offer);
    } else {
      if (offer.frequency - i <= offer.used) {
        console.log("True calling", offer.frequency - i);
        offer.isAvailable = "false";
        newOffers.push(offer);
      } else {
        console.log("False calling", offer.frequency - i);
        offer.isAvailable = "true";
        newOffers.push(offer);
      }
    }
  }
});
console.log("All offers ", newOffers);
```

I have assign "isAvailable" value "true" or "false" to offer object and all condition working perfectly but when I print the "newOffers" array after complete the loop process the all "isAvailable" values is "false"

What wrong with this code? can someone help me?

Comment: Include a sample of `response.data` and what is the expected output.

Comment: So do more debugging: you have two cases where you set it to `true`, prove to yourself (before you prove to us) that the preconditions for those cases even apply. Because if you only see `false` it stands to reason that `offer.used === 0` is false (don't use `==`, use `===` unless you know exactly why you need type coercion) _and_ that `offer.frequency - i <= offer.used` is false. Also, if you're using `let`, don't also use the legacy `var`, stick with `let` for mutables and `const` for immutables.

Comment: Your code could use a little refactoring, but I don't see any reason for why the thing you describe should be happening.

Comment: ok its working now I just replace this line "var offer = element;" to "let offer = {
                        ...element
                    };"  this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript when you use `=` operator for the objects, it doesn't work like as you expect. You should change your code like this if you are familiar with ES6:

```
var offer = {...element}
```

or

```
var offer = Object.assign({}, element);
```

Read [this](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects/)